# Parallel.For not handling lock properly

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

I've done the following test:

```
private static object threadLocker = new object();

private static long threadStaticVar;
public static long ThreadStaticVar
{
    get
    {
        lock (threadLocker)
        {
            return threadStaticVar;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        lock (threadLocker)
        {
            threadStaticVar = value;
        }
    }
}

Parallel.For(0, 20000, (x) =>
{
    //lock (threadLocker) // works with this lock
    //{
        ThreadStaticVar++;
    //}
});
```

This `Parallel.For` invokes the method passing the values from 0 to 19999. So it would execute 20k times.

If I don't wrap `ThreadStaticVar++;` with a `lock`, even though it has a lock on its `get` and `set`, the result will not be `20000`. If I remove the comment bars and lock it inside the `.For` it gets the right value.

My question is: How does it work? Why the lock on the `get` and `set` doesn't work? Why it works only inside my `For`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `++` operator isn't an atomic increment. There will be a call to `get` followed by a call to `set`, and those calls can be interleaved among different threads since the lock is only on each individual operation. Think of it like this:

```
lock {tmp = var}
lock {var = tmp+1}
```

Those locks don't look so effective now, do they?

Answer (score 2):

In your example `ThreadStaricVar++` is not an *atomic operation*.

More accurately, `++` is not an atomic operation as it locks your getter, then increment the value, and then locks your setter to set the value. Between these two anything can happen :)

To do it properly I would recommend to use object-oriented programming instead of this procedural code. Just implement an `Increment()` method in your object and make it responsible to lock and do `++` inside this method. In your parallel loop you just *command* your object what to do, now it this object's responsibility to make it happen and figure out how to do it.

So you just implement your lock *within* the Increment() method and have no problems anywhere outside (really, consumers shouldn't know and shouldn't even think about such issues).

Answer (score 1):

You can rename `threadStaticVar` and make it public .  Then, use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zs86dyzy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

However, also consider whether a parallel for is appropriate.  Even if the real code is more complex, running in parallel with locking may not be your best option.